# How is ranking calculated in the Top Users page?

Tags: support, reputation, top-users

The Top Users page, sorted for this month's rankings, says I have 11 total reputation points. That's not true, because I actually have 698 total reputation points. Strangely, my ranking is placed in-between users who have 500-600 reputation points.

> https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2015-01-01/4356188#4356188

[image: My reputation is incorrect, and my rank is weirdly placed!]

Also, many users say, "not previously ranked," on them, even though they must have been ranked before. For example, `Smith3` has been a member for over 4 years, and `heath` has been a member for over 5 years. But both users are "not previously ranked."

I also observed that the other users aren't even sorted in order. In the screenshot, users' reputation are sorted in the order of 611, 621, 584, 592, 11, 605, and 419.

Are all these things bugs? If they're designed as intended, then how is your rank calculated in the Top Users page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have sorted by month's reputation which is 10 for all users shown above. users with reputation below 200 are not tracked that is why some users are not shown (because in previous month they might have below 200 reputation)

Answer (score 8):

You start off with 1 reputation.

In January you received one upvote, taking you up to 11 total reputation -- but having achieved 10 in the month.

Comment: But why am I ranked between users that earned a lot more than me?

Comment: Well, you're not. The league is based on how much reputation you earned in **that month**. The users around you also have 10 month reputation.

Comment: And the ordering within the same reputations grouping is random.

Comment: I am curious why did this question receive so much of a negative response and downvotes? I was about to post something similar :p. `God saved me`

Comment: @DevendraLattu it shows very little effort on part of the asker, and asker had made a series of truly terrible meta posts that bordered on trolling in a short space of time.